# SignalR: Not a valid web socket request

Tags: websocket, signalr, iis-8

Just migrated to windows 2012 and turned on the feature websockets in IIS 8. But Signalr isn't working anymore, it's trying to connect with websockets and stays pending forever (seen in chrome network tools).

If I look in elmah I see a lot of:  System.InvalidOperationException: Not a valid web socket request errors. With the connection type UPGRADE.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

I'm using signalr 1.1.2 in an mvc 4 app.

Comment: You can check if your browser supports websocket in http://caniuse.com/websockets
You can test your browser in http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Finally, you can use Fiddler to inspect http traffic and ensure the request contains the headers defined in websocket spec http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ietf-announce/current/msg09663.html

Comment: Got websockets working now (by creating a new mvc 4 project and copying everything in it, as a last resort). But I still see the 'Not a valid web socket request' errors in the logs. Is this by design? Can I catch those errors?